# Symfony's sfYaml::load returning a stange value

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, yaml

In a Symfony project, I have the following php code inside a YML file.  I was hoping this code would read another yml file and modify the content based upon its value.  However, sfYaml::load is returning a string instead of an array.  Any ideas why this might be?

In the following code, I expected $s to contain an array, but instead it contains a string with the value "../config/server_settings.yml".

From databases.yml:

```
dsn:      mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydbname<?php $s = sfYaml::load('../config/server_settings.yml');var_dump($s); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's treating your input as a string of yml content, possibly because it can't find the file. Try using the full path or some quick debugging with `is_file('../config/server_settings.yml')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Changing it to use sfConfig::get('sf_config_dir') fixed the problem.  I was thrown off initially because it wasn't throwing an exception or error.

Comment: @Daniel Glad to hear. I had to dig into sfYaml to come up with that suggestion. Functions that take strings OR file-paths for the same param are always a little funky.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to define custom settings.

Perhaps this page might help you out: 
http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToCacheCustomConfiguration